# getElementsByTagName Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, tags

I'm trying to populate an HMTL page with XML data. This code used to work but I must have changed something because now nothing happens on the button clicks. Could it potentially be a problem with the server? And in that case what changed? The line where things appear to stop working is getElementsByTagName, all alerts before that line still work.

Here's the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDocTraditional() {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {


            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                //alert("Xhttp.readyState = " + xhttp.readyState);

                var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML; 
                //There is something wrong with this line
                var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("trad")[0].childNodes[0];
                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = item.nodeValue;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "data.xml", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    function loadXMLDocSimple() {


        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            //alert("Xhttp.status = " + xhttp.status);
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

                var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML; //Using a variable doesn't work bc/ of the getElements method?
                var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("simp")[0].childNodes[0];
                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = item.nodeValue;

            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "data.xml", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

And here's the XML:

```
<dictionary>
<word>
    <title>Ubiquitous</title>
    <trad>This is the traditional defintion ubiquitous</trad>
    <simp>This is the simplified defintion hopefully ubiquitous</simp>
</word>

<word>
    <title>Lithe</title>
    <trad>This is the traditional defintion of lithe</trad>
    <simp>This is the simplified defintion of lithe hopefully</simp>
</word>
```

Comment: What do you get with `alert(xmlDoc);` before the line in question. *(Using `console.log(...)` is nicer than `alert(...)`.)* Are there any errors in your developer console?

Comment: With `alert(xmlDoc);` it returns null, which I don't think is what it should be returning. Then I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null`

Comment: How about when you log `xhttp.responseText`?

Comment: Okay that's really weird. When I did `responseText` it printed out an old version of my XML doc. It's not the current version that the server is running. I re-uploaded the XML doc and it still pops up with the older version.

Comment: I don't know if the browser would cache the old data, but it may be worth clearing the cache or if you have the developer tools open, setting the option to always fetch data from the server.

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything. It still seems to be just the `getElementsByTagName` call.

Comment: Is the old data valid XML? Seems like it's not getting parsed or the request is failing. How about the `Content-Type` header being sent by the server? Is it `text/xml` or `application/xml`? What happens if you set `xhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml")` before sending the request? Have you checked the `Network` tab in your dev tools to make sure the request is actually succeeding?

Comment: The old XML was valid, I only changed a few tags to make the new version. `Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'overrideMimeType' on 'XMLHttpRequest': MimeType cannot be overridden when the state is LOADING or DONE.` Also I think in HTML5 there are no more content types and all I have is `<meta charset="utf-8" />.` And for the network tab, yes, the request shows up and follows through.

Comment: You should be calling `overrideMimeType` before you send the request. Aside from that, I'm just not sure what the issue could be. Given that `responseXML` is `null`, it would seem that either the request is failing, the parsing is failing, or the parsing isn't being attempted *(because of `Content-Type` not indicating `XML` data)*.